# Java Socket Multiple Connections

Tags: java, sockets

How do I allow multiple connections on my socket?

Before you ask, I've already looked at related topics and I was unable to make it work.  I am using a thread, however I believe I am using it wrong.  Here is my code:

Thanks.

**Server.java**

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import entities.Player;

public class Server extends JFrame {

static ServerSocket serverSocket;
static Socket clientSocket;
static Socket socket;
public static int port = 43594;
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
Player player = new Player();
public static JLabel players;
public static String s;

public void initialize() throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    frame();
    for (;;) {
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(clientSocket)).start();
    }
}

public void frame() {
    JLabel status = new JLabel("Server is running on 43594");
    s = String.valueOf(player.playerCount);
    players = new JLabel(s);
    panel.add(status);
    panel.add(players);
    add(panel);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

**ConnectionHandler.java**

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

import entities.Player;

public class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
private Socket clientSocket;
Player player = new Player();

public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket) {
    player.playerCount++;
    Server.s = String.valueOf(player.playerCount);
    Server.players.setText(Server.s);
    clientSocket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String nextline;
        try {
            while ((nextline = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(nextline);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            player.playerCount--;
            Server.s = String.valueOf(player.playerCount);
            Server.players.setText(Server.s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Client connecting and disconnecting works fine, I just can't connect more than one client at once.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why sockets are declared as static ?. you dont need to.

Comment: _"I figured out why it can't handle multiple clients. It was related to some class objects I made, and static variables. It's fixed though :) –"_ You can post your own answer and accept it if you want, to close out the question.

Comment: You should not have any 'static Socket' members in your server class. You have two. Remove them. They are concurrency bugs either happening or waiting to happen.

Answer (score -1):

*"I figured out why it can't handle multiple clients. It was related to some class objects I made, and static variables. It's fixed though :) –"*